# Keynote : export slides to pdf with notes

Tags: pdf, keynote

I would like to export my Keynote slides to pdf with the presenter notes. The layout of the resulting pdf is not good : the slides are scaled down on each page, and the text of the presenter note is not aligned with the slides (see screnshot)
Is there a way to change that layout ? I tried the option "print to pdf", but I can't get good result.

If it's impossible to get nice pdf from Keynote, do you know any other app that could handle this correctly?

[image: example of pdf page]

Answer (score 1):

This is a cosmetic bug you could report to Apple.

Here is my best approach I used to get a decent PDF.
In printing menu, select `Keynote > Print: > Handout > Add Notes`
[image]

Comment: But that workaround doesn't solve the problem of the scaled-down slide and the non-aligned text ?

Comment: You are right. This doesn't answer your question. Let me search back in my previous Keynote files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Powerpoint, one easy option is to export from Keynote to Powerpoint (pptx), and then print from Powerpoint to PDF with the Notes layout.

Powerpoint does a slightly better job of formatting presenter notes. They're better aligned, in a larger font size, and the default aspect ratio is portrait. Not perfect, but looks a bit nicer than the Keynote export style.

[image: Powerpoint print dialog]